# Expand/Collapse with + and -

Tags: javascript, frontend

Hey I am looking to create an expandable/collapse div, I have it working fine with the following code which works fine but the first click doesnt seem to do anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showme(id, linkid) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        var toggleLink = document.getElementById(linkid);
        if (divid.style.display == 'block') {
            toggleLink.innerHTML = 'Top five loves +';
            divid.style.display = 'none';        }
        else {
            toggleLink.innerHTML = 'Top five loves -';
            divid.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>

<a id="toggler" onclick="showme('loves', this.id);" href="#">Top five loves</a>
<div id="loves">
<ol>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
        <li>Fourth item</li>
        <li>Fifth item</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

[image: plus minus expand/collapse]

Thanks :)

Comment: On a side note, element ids should be unique.

Comment: that was just for testing purposes., thank you thou! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show/hide, why dont you make one element to show and one for hiding?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTop5(){
        document.getElementById("top5opener").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("top5").style.display = "block";
    }
    function hideTop5(){
        document.getElementById("top5").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("top5opener").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
<a id="top5opener" href="javascript:showTop5();">Show Top 5</a>
<div id="top5" style="display:none">
    <a href="javascript:hideTop5();">Hide Top 5</a>
    <div class="yourElements">
        <ol>
            ...
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your buttons/links just neet a little bit styling to look like you want

btw.: you can/should use some framework like jQuery :) so your javascript would be smaller and easier to write

Answer (score 1):

Just use another toggle function (or edit the one you have) to toggle between a `+` and a `-`.  Use a paragraph element (or similar) to hold the `+` and `-`.

Comment: I've got it working but the first time i click it it doesn't do anything after that it works how I want it to.

Comment: I'm finding your code a bit hard to ready, you are suffixing your elements with both id and link, they are elements....also why do you have only one of your + and - visual clues in a span?  Also remove all the extra spaces unless you need them for some reason.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle.net of this behavior?

Comment: it is likely that the initial state of style.display is not block but something else like inline.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to javascript, and playing around with it quite a bit. I had the spans on the + and - because I am going to be styling those separate to the text (floating right).